# How to obtain VMWare ESXi logging from Vsphere?

Tags: vmware-esxi, powercli

How to obtain VMWare ESXi log and store it in our local machine?

Can it be acheived using VMWare powerCLI?

( I hope in log file i can get what are all the guest machines were utilized and how long . Is it true?)

Comment: You can get all that stuff via vCenter.

Answer (score 2):

Obtaining ESXi diagnostic logs can be done a couple different ways: Through the VI client, or through the API. The PowerCLI method is listed in the following KB article.

http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1027932

Regarding whether or not the guest machine utilization is in there, I'd need more info about what you are looking for.

Comment: I am junior admin in VMware. As of now i am only looking for couple of information. 1. Guest machine utilization. 2. Snapshots taken in host machine for the day. I don't know what are all the other things can be achieved by diagnosing the log. What experts mainly do with VMware logs?

Comment: Do you know if you are using vCenter Server, or just ESXi? A good way to tell is to look at the license on the summary tab of the host in your vSphere client.

Comment: I am just using Free ESXi . I am not having vCenter. I think PowerCLi can still read information.

Comment: Free ESXi does not include API access. API access is required for PowerCLI.